# How to create roles and assign to users in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, roles

I was working on a website and I needed to create two types of users: A client and an administrator. The admin will have the privilege of adding and removing blog. How can I do that. I am using MVC5 and Individual Users. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please describe in more detail which steps you have taken so far and where exactly the problem lies?

Comment: Hi @youssef thanks for the reply. I am new to MVC. I have only created the application so far and was starting from managing the users.

Comment: Follow this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc/